# HOWTO limit Access on AzureDevops to just being able to access one git-branch

Tags: git, security, azure-devops, branch

We want an external party to have access (R/W) to only one branch in our project. They should not be able to see backlog, pipeline, ....

I've created a group for them, gave that group 'contribute : allow' rights on that branch. 
They do claim not to have access to that branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** SOLVED ***
The missing links are:
- project settings | security. 'View project-level information' : 'Allow'
- project settings | repositories. Grant desired rights to that group on the top level 'git repositories'